# proving that a certain function defined using integrals is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that the function

$$f(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt $$

I'm very confused here, because the variable "x" appears inside the integral, and not in the form $\int_{0}^{x}$ as always, I don't know how can I do here. Please help me!

Comment: Treat $x$ as constant. Because we are integrating with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$
\int\limits_0^\pi\frac{\sin(xt)}{t}dt
=\int\limits_0^\pi\frac{\sin(xt)}{xt}d(xt)
=\int\limits_0^{\pi x}\frac{\sin(s)}{s}ds
$$

Comment: I did not understand what you did

Comment: Another attempt, try change of variables $s=xt$